# Adding C Wire as simple as C to C?

Tags: furnace, thermostat-c-wire, central-air

Short version: I ran a new 2-strand wire from my thermostat to the furnace/air handler unit to provide spare wires since the existing 5 wires are used up and I need a C. **Is hooking up the C wire as simple as just grabbing (and labeling, of course) one of the 2 new strands I ran, and hooking it to C at both ends?**

Longer version:
My thermostat currently has 5 wires from one cable, none of which are attached to C. The tstat runs on batteries, but this is not great since they run out at odd times, maybe while we're gone. (That happened once even though the batteries were pretty fresh, and the house was awful -- and now the blower in the only 5-year-old Trane is burned out, so I wonder if the thing wasn't being ill treated by the thermo while the batteries were depleting.)

[image: current stat wiring]

So, I've got R and Rc jumpered, White, Green, Yellow, and Y2 is using the blue. At the furnace, I've got all this below, but it's 6 strand, hooked to a bunch of other strands and runs up the lines:

[image: furnace hookup]

The gray housed 5 wire comes in from the linkage of a water shutoff / floor flood switch and a condensate pump. (It must also be hooked into the AC unit outside because doesn't that need to run to common?)

I could not easily pull out and replace the existing 5 strand because it hooks a 90 degree angle somewhere inside the wall, so I ran an extra 18-2 from the thermostat to the furnace.

I'd like to hook up the current, battery powered tstat (which the specs say runs on power via common) so it doesn't need batteries. Eventually a fancier wifi one will go in so I can keep tabs on the place while we're gone.

**Is hooking up the C wire as simple as just grabbing (and labeling, of course) one of the 2 new strands I ran, and hooking it to C at both ends?**

Answer (score 2):

Yup, it's that simple.

Since the AC's off anyway (because the Trane blower burned out after 5 years) I figured I had little to lose by just hooking it up and checking to see if it powered the Thermostat as it should. It does.